# Raspberry Pi 4, with a button's press glowing the led and taking an image

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, gpio

So I am working on an experiment where when a button is pressed it should glow the LED for      0.5 seconds and take a image at 0.25 seconds ( or somewhere when the LED is glowing). For starters I was writing the code just to take a image when LED was on without the time constraints

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import cv2
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)


GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)
time.sleep(1)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s = 0


    
while True:
    ret, image = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("Image Test",image)
    if GPIO.input(10) == GPIO.HIGH:
        s+=1
        GPIO.output(16,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        cv2.imwrite("/home/richgapple/Desktop/python/test%d.jpg" % s, image)
        print("Image must be taken")
        print(GPIO.input(10))

    else:
        GPIO.output(16,GPIO.LOW)
        
    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord('b'):
        break
    
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the code I wrote for that to happen but in the images taken, only from the second image i can see that the LED is glowing and not from the first image

[image]
[image]

I have tired giving time.sleep(1) before image was taken and also cv2.waitKey(1) as well but nothing seemed to work.
will help if i can get an answer as soon as possible!!!

Comment: It looks like a camera latency issue. Using `time.sleep(0.1)` before `cv2.imwrite` is probably just making things worse. Try dropping (not saving) the first frame or two, and save one or two extra frames at the end. What is the framerate?

Comment: It's an small otoscopic camera and the seller hasn't provided any exact framerate either